# Sending emails in the background in the Ionic2 app

Tags: email, ionic2, gmail-api, ionic-native

I have to send email with user's location within set period of time. I was using Background Geolocation plugin and it's working fine (sending it to the local host). The better way is to send the data with email - it's easier to parse the data and it's more universal and common. I have to send the data to hardcoded email without opening other apps. Is there any way to do it? Maybe using Gmail API?

Comment: If you authorize your app at the beginning, I think you can send email in background using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) then refresh credentials when necessary ([Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)).  You can also use [email plugin](https://devdactic.com/sending-emails-with-images-in-ionic-cordova/) or [Rackspace Mailgun API](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/05/send-emails-ionic-2-mobile-app-via-rackspace-mailgun-api/) that you can use to send email. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Can I use the code for nodejs (via your first link to Gmail docs) in Ionic app?